# Can I set a specific “Release Date” after my app is approved by Apple?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have been developing an app for one of my client and I had submitted the app and got it approved. When I was submitting the app binary, the client was not sure about the release date so I chose to manually release the version. Now the client wants it on a specific date and time which I think I might miss because the timezone the app has to be launched in will most probably be my sleeping time.

The app has been approved by Apple and current status on the iTunes Connect is `Pending Developer Release`, can I now schedule this app to launch on a particular date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not yet a feature on iTunes Connect. What I wanted was to schedule the release date for the app after the app was approved by Apple and my app status was `Pending Developer Release`.

Setting a scheduled release date can **ONLY** be done before app is submitted for review.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can set it App release date with specific time.

**Note :** The main point is that you can set release date only that which will coming after your app published or approved by apple.

[image]

Once above task is done just press on **"Save"**. Now, Its automatically release when your given date & specific time is matched.

Comment: I am already past this point and I selected `Manually release this version` my App status was `Pending Developer Release`. This solution is not correct

Comment: If you choose manually release this version option, then it shows you pending developer release status for your app  means that you can published you app later on but if you want to set specific date on which your app is automatically published then you can choose 3rd option.

Now, if Your app shows pending developer release then also you can set app published or release date with time because on our side confirmation is remain for publishing app.

Comment: I chose the first option when submitting the app. I don't get this option after app gets approved by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

As you can mention that but it is related to Pricing ... when it should available on appstore. WHile uploading app for review there is one option where you can set if you want to release it as soon as it approved from apple or you want to manually release it .

Yes you can do that

refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html) ......

This option is available in Pricing and availability section.[image]

Comment: Isn't that just when the pricing for the app starts / ends, not the actual publish date of the app?

Comment: yes it is related to pricing as they said but it is possible .... can't add new version so not able to view all options

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help. I couldn't set a particular time. I guess this is not possible. I wanted to set a time as well which is not possible after App has been approved and the status is `Pending Developer Release`. I had to wake up and I released the app manually